# How to enable background scrolling when Popover is opened? (React, React Native, Native-Base)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I'm using the Popover component from [NativeBase](https://docs.nativebase.io) to create my popover:

```
const SettingsButton: React.FC<Props> = () => {
    return (
        <Popover
            trigger={(triggerProps) => {
                return (
                    <Button {...triggerProps} variant={'ghost'}>
                        <HamburgerIcon size="xl" color="lightText" />
                    </Button>
                );
            }}
        >
            <SettingsPopover />
        </Popover>
    );
};
```

(Full App is [here](https://github.com/Fabian5150/user-app), Popover is [here](https://github.com/Fabian5150/user-app/blob/main/src/components/SettingsButton.tsx))

I want the Page behind the Popover to be scrollable, similar to how you can scroll the [Github](https://github.com) Page when your Settings/Profile-Popover in the right is opened.

The best thing I could come up with so far, is to put

```
onOpen={() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll';
}}
onClose={() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}}
```

in my Popover-Component, but that adds a second scrollbar and closes the Popover directly when scrolling (and in the mobile version of the app it doesn't change anything), it's a bit of a shitty solution and I think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `position: fixed;` on the popover may do what you want.

`position: fixed;` makes the popover stay in position regardless of where the viewport is, you can the configure where it displays using `top`, `left`, or other CSS.

> fixed
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms Spec), or the will-change property is set to transform, in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block. (Note that there are browser inconsistencies with perspective and filter contributing to containing block formation.) Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

[position - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but do you know how I can add the position with typescript?
Because I can't just add it as a style prop `style={{position: "fixed"}}` to <Popover> as I could with simple jsx. :(  
  
(It gives me a type error: (...)
  Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InterfacePopoverProps &(...); )

Comment: Looking at the docs, it looks like you need to 'extend the default theme': https://docs.nativebase.io/popover#h2-styling and https://docs.nativebase.io/customizing-components. 

Let me know if this works and ill update the answer